# How to change mysql_connect into PDO. Updating form

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm new to programming and just changed from mysql to mysqli, but when i found my login script on the net it was written with PDO. So now i'm onto that ;D

How can i change this php file to use PDO to update my database?!

Config.php

```
<?php 

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
$username = "usr"; 
$password = "pass"; 
$host = "host"; 
$dbname = "databasee"; 

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username,  $password, $options); } 
catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex- >getMessage());} 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
session_start(); 
?>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
$connect = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
require("config.php");
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die("Redirecting to ../index.php");
} else {
    // get data from model form meny.php
    $valt_objekt_id = mysqli_escape_string($connect, strip_tags($_POST['valt_objekt_id']));
    $valt_objekt_nummer = mysqli_escape_string($connect, strip_tags($_POST['valt_objekt_nummer']));
    $valt_objekt_alias = mysqli_escape_string($connect, strip_tags($_POST['valt_objekt_alias']));
    $valt_objekt_leverans = mysqli_escape_string($connect, strip_tags($_POST['valt_objekt_leverans']));
    $valt_objekt_adress = mysqli_escape_string($connect,  strip_tags($_POST['valt_objekt_adress']));

    // update database
    $sql = "UPDATE `objekt` 
            SET `objekt_nummer` = '$valt_objekt_nummer', 
                `objekt_alias`= '$valt_objekt_alias', 
                `objekt_leverans` = '$valt_objekt_leverans',
                `objekt_adress` = '$valt_objekt_adress'
            WHERE `objekt_id` = '$valt_objekt_id'";

     //this is required for almost every mysqli_* function
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); //the example
    //mysqli can update multiple rows at a time

    // if successfully updated. 
    if($result){
        echo "Uppdateringen lyckades <br> <a href='../objekt.php'>Gå tillbaka</a>";
    } else {
     echo mysql_error();
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the PDO version of your script:

```
if($_POST) {
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die("Redirecting to ../index.php");
} else {
    require("config.php");
    // get data from model form meny.php
    $valt_objekt_id = $_POST['valt_objekt_id'];
    $valt_objekt_nummer = $_POST['valt_objekt_nummer'];
    $valt_objekt_alias = $_POST['valt_objekt_alias'];
    $valt_objekt_leverans = $_POST['valt_objekt_leverans'];
    $valt_objekt_adress = $_POST['valt_objekt_adress'];

    // update database
    $sql = "UPDATE `objekt` 
            SET `objekt_nummer` = :objekt_nummer, 
                `objekt_alias`= :objekt_alias, 
                `objekt_leverans` = :objekt_leverans,
                `objekt_adress` = :objekt_adress
            WHERE `objekt_id` = :objekt_id";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $result = stmt->execute(array(':objekt_nummer' => $valt_objekt_nummer, 
                                  ':objekt_alias' => $valt_objekt_alias, 
                                  ':objekt_leverans' => $valt_objekt_leverans,
                                  ':objekt_adress' = $valt_objekt_adress,
                                  ':objekt_id' => $valt_objekt_id
                            )); 

    if($result){
        echo "Uppdateringen lyckades <br> <a href='../objekt.php'>Gå tillbaka</a>";
    } else {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
    }
}
}
```

Learn more about [***PDO prepared statments***](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I did set "$stmt" and adress' =>"

Comment: Aslo, i moved "require" and puted it after if($POST). Now it works! Thank alot man!